# replace variables in a list with combinations of elements

Tags: python

I want to replace variables in a list with combination of elements.
To be more specific:

I have these two lists

```
liste1 = [1,2,3,'X','X',4]
liste2 = [5,6,7]
```

and I want to get a list containing the elements below :

```
[1,2,3,5,6,4]
[1,2,3,5,7,4]
[1,2,3,6,7,4]
[1,2,3,6,5,4]
[1,2,3,7,5,4]
[1,2,3,7,6,4]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make it ?

Comment: Your first list isn't valid Python code unless you defined an `X` variable before - or did you mean `'X'`? Please update your question.

Comment: it's done. I meant 'X'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: In particular, is your difficulty in finding the permutations to use to replace the `'X'`s? Is it doing the replacements? Or is it something else? The actual answer is--Yes, I do have an idea how to make it. But you need to show us more before I give specific help.

Comment: @lamps will there always be just 2 `X` placeholders in the first list? Will they always be side by side inside the list?

Comment: I have no idea of how i can deal with that. I am a beginner in coding and python. 
The problem i'm dealing with it's how to add the permutations of 2 in the list instead of 'X'.

Comment: @Ralf Not necesserly, the 'X' can be anywhere and not always side inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
from itertools import permutations

liste1 = [1, 2, 3, 'X', 'X', 4]
liste2 = [5, 6, 7]

def replacements(liste1, liste2):
    x_indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(liste1) if val == 'X']
    nb = len(x_indices)
    for perm in permutations(liste2, nb):
        l1 = liste1[:] # if we want to preserve the original and yield different lists
        for i, new_val in zip(x_indices, perm):
            l1[i] = new_val
        yield l1

for r in replacements(liste1, liste2):
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 4]
```

We first list the indices where 'X' appears, then generate the permutations of as many elements of `liste2`. For each permutation, we replace the 'X's.